# Eclipse view of currently running apps with their output consoles

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, microservices, sts

In eclipse, I am looking for away to show all the currently running apps in an easy way, something similar for SpringBoot Dashboard in Spring Tool Suite, but not for SpringBoot apps.

The reason behind that we are building microservices based on our own framework, and when running a bunch of microsrvices, their console-tracking becomes not easy.

Currently I solve the problem by opening multiple console views, then pin the console of each app (microservice), however, this may not be practical, and there should be an easier way.

I have tried 'Runner' plugin, it is only useful for running apps, but it cant attach the app to its console.

Any Ideas?

Below a screenshot of my current approach.

Thanks in advance
JK

[image: Screenshot of my current approach]

Comment: Eclipse is a Development environment. It isn't intended for running or monitoring production programs.

Comment: Use IntelliJ ;)